Resolve error i want to import " instruction as token_instruction,"
use anchor_lang::prelude::;
use {
anchor_lang::{
prelude::,
solana_program::program::invoke,
system_program,
},
anchor_spl::{
associated_token,
token,
},
mpl_token_metadata::{
ID as TOKEN_METADATA_ID,
instruction as token_instruction,
},
};
error
error[E0432]: unresolved import mpl_token_metadata::instruction
--> programs/nft-marketplace/src/lib.rs:14:9
|
14 |         instruction as token_instruction,
|         -----------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
|         |
|         no instruction in the root
|         help: a similar name exists in the module: instructions
|
= help: consider importing one of these items instead:
solana_program::address_lookup_table::instruction
solana_program::instruction
solana_program::stake::instruction
solana_program::vote::instruction

Do you have the Metaplex crate installed?

Try renaming it to mpl_token_intruction.
Use mpl_token_metadata::instruction as mpl_token_instruction;

Ref https://docs.rs/mpl-token-metadata/latest/mpl_token_metadata/
